Unable to get jupyterlab-git extension working in TLJH (The Littlest Jupyter Hub)
We are currently in the process of automating AWS EC2 image builds that have TLJH installed along with some basic extensions. I’m using an Ansible playbook to handle the TLJH installation. When the EC2 instance is launched, we have a path specified in our load balancer to redirect to the hub server on there.
I am able to successfully access JupyterLab via our URL and it works fine. However, I am unable to see the JupyterLab-Git panel in the UI. I have even tried manually installing the extension in the EC2 shell; it shows up in the server and lab extension lists but does not show up in the UI even after reloading TLJH. Unfortunately, I’ve been down this rabbit hole for two whole days with nothing to show for it, except a ton of frustration.
I really need someone to lay out the exact commands (including venv activation) required to successfully install extensions and have their corresponding UI elements show up in JupyterLab after reloading/respawning the user’s server.
Thanks in advance…

See the discussion here for updates: In particular here has it working with TLJH on a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 VM. And here says, the insightful component was, "The extension needs to be installed in the user environment."

After spending some time away from this, I was able to finally identify the root of the problem.
Since we're using nginx as a reverse proxy to redirect to the EC2's Jupyter server, our Ansible playbook applies nginx hardening. The limit_conn properties of the hardening were responsible for the break. Upon commenting them out, the extension GUI worked as expected.
